# Android - Setting time data according to GMT

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can I organize the time data I keep in a string according to the user's time?

For example;
Default data (Hour / minute / second) = 03:48:21

This data of a user with GMT + 2;

It should see as 02: 48.21.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```java
OffsetTime
.of(
    LocalTime.parse( "03:48:21" ) ,
    ZoneOffset.ofHours( 2 )
)
.withOffsetSameInstant​( 
    ZoneOffset.UTC 
)
.toString()
```

> 01:48:21Z

## Use date-time types

> How can I organize the time data I keep in a string

Do not use a `String` to store other types. If you have date-time values, use date-time types. Java provides the industry-leading date-time types in the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## `LocalTime`

If `03:48:21` is meant to be a time-of-day, use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html).

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse( "03:48:21" ) ;
```

## Time-of-day without date makes no sense in zone or offset

> … according to the user's time? … data of a user with GMT + 2 … 03:48:21 …should see as 02: 48.21

To my mind, logically a time-of-day without a date cannot be placed in the context of a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

## `OffsetTime`

The *java.time* classes offer the [`OffsetTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetTime.html) class. I assume this class exists merely to support standard SQL which mentions a time-of-day with offset. However, this concept makes no sense in my opinion. But if you insist on using it, so be it.

Specify a [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) to couple with your `LocalTime`.

```java
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "03:48:21" ) ;
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( 2 ) ;
OffsetTime ot = OffsetTime.of( lt , offset ) ;
OffsetTime otUtc = ot.withOffsetSameInstant​( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;

System.out.println( "ot.toString(): " + ot ) ;
System.out.println( "otUtc.toString(): " + otUtc ) ;
```

See this code [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/gRa4LB).

> ot.toString(): 03:48:21+02:00
>
> otUtc.toString(): 01:48:21Z

The `Z` on the end of that output represents UTC, an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds, `+00:00`. The `Z` is pronounced “Zulu” per aviation/military tradition.